# Are questions about website content welcome here?

Tags: discussion

It is a user experience problem (at least I think so), but has little to do with graphics/graphical design. Also I'm not sure how subjective it is, and is it considered open-ended.

e.g. is putting music charts (on a separate page, along other offtopic, like places to go out) on internet/tech website aimed at young people considered to engage visitors or just annoy them?

If this is a wrong place, is there a site on SE where this may fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe the question you have, yes, that is probably on-topic for here. Content is very much a User Experience issue so in general we're happy to help out there.

However, there are some caveats:

- If it's a 'can you review my website' type question, that's not really suited to this site. The same goes for 'which looks best, X or Y' sort of things.
- If it's a very broad question without specific details, such as 'where should I put my Contact Us button' then that's also not really suited (although could probably be edited to be a better fit).

There are other things to bear in mind too. Have a check of the [about] page for more specific guidence to what is suited to this site.

It needs to be an objective question, not something purely subjective, and one that can be explicitly (or at least hypothetically) answered with a correct answer.

Think of Stack Exchange as a repository for common (and uncommon) questions and their respective answers. Someone somewhere will likely have a question and think *'I bet someone else has had this problem in the past'* so they'll turn to the internet to ask *'What should I do when I have X situation?'* and they'll hopefully find themselves on a Stack Exchange website with a useful answer to an exact, or highly related question to their own.

That's what Stack Exchange is for - a repository for questions.

Providing your question is the sort of thing that is going to be of use to other people, even if you think the actual chances of someone having the same issue are small, then it's good to go ahead. If it's a question that's only ever going to be of benefit to you and your situation (such as a 'review my website' question) then it's not suited.

Having said all that, your question is possibly one that would just be answered with 'have you spoken to your users to find out what they actually want / need?'